# Strange IP packet payload corruption

Tags: router, ipv4, nat, internet

I'm working on developing a transport protocol layered directly atop IP and while performing an experiment to see how routers on the internet would react to an undefined protocol I've observed some unusual behavior.

My experiment involves sending a plain IPv4 packet from one host on the public internet to another. Both hosts are typical home-user setups:

`[Host] -> [Router/Modem Billion 7300GRA] -> (Internet)`

Simple enough right? Well apparently not as what I'm observing is that although the packets are being received, there is a pattern where-in the first 4 bytes of every other packet's payload is being nulled. Below is a sample:

```
0000   00 1c c0 93 6a 7f 00 04 ed 9b 53 26 08 00 45 00  ....j.....S&..E.
0010   00 1d 37 ff 00 00 70 fd 27 2b 3a a2 ef 6d c0 a8  ..7...p.'+:..m..
0020   00 02 00 00 00 00 4d 53 47 00 01 aa 00 00 4d 53  ......MSG.....MS
0030   00 00 00 00 88 64 63 78 00 00 0b 00              .....dcx....

0000   00 1c c0 93 6a 7f 00 04 ed 9b 53 26 08 00 45 00  ....j.....S&..E.
0010   00 1d 38 08 00 00 70 fd 27 22 3a a2 ef 6d c0 a8  ..8...p.'":..m..
0020   00 02 54 45 53 54 4d 53 47 00 02 aa 53 54 4d 53  ..TESTMSG...STMS
0030   00 00 00 00 88 64 65 78 00 00 0b 00              .....dex....

0000   00 1c c0 93 6a 7f 00 04 ed 9b 53 26 08 00 45 00  ....j.....S&..E.
0010   00 1d 38 15 00 00 70 fd 27 15 3a a2 ef 6d c0 a8  ..8...p.'.:..m..
0020   00 02 00 00 00 00 4d 53 47 00 03 aa 00 00 4d 53  ......MSG.....MS
0030   00 00 00 00 88 64 1e bc 80 00 33 db              .....d....3.

0000   00 1c c0 93 6a 7f 00 04 ed 9b 53 26 08 00 45 00  ....j.....S&..E.
0010   00 1d 38 21 00 00 70 fd 27 09 3a a2 ef 6d c0 a8  ..8!..p.'.:..m..
0020   00 02 54 45 53 54 4d 53 47 00 04 aa 53 54 4d 53  ..TESTMSG...STMS
0030   00 00 00 00 88 64 04 00 00 00 89 ff              .....d......
```

This pattern continues seemingly ad infinitum. The payload structure is expected to be:

```
[8 bytes] "TESTMSG\0"
[1 bytes] A counter incremented per packet (added to verify it wasn't some strange ordering issue)
```

I'm also using 0xFD as the transport protocol identifier in the IP header as it's designated by IANA for "experimental use"

I've verified it's not a programming error at the sender via Wireshark and I've also reversed the tx/rx roles between hosts.

My current hypothesis is that the problem lies with one of the routers of which both hosts sit behind so I'm hoping maybe if someone here has knowledge of their firmware implementation they could shed some light on this. (The fact it's the first 4 bytes suggests to me it may have to do with NAT since that offset correlates with the src/dst ports of TCP/UDP)

Thanks,

-Matt

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but your packets don't match your problem description.  You said that you sent the packets over the internet; however, the src mac, dest mac, and TTL are all *unchanged* between the packets you allegedly sent and received.  This makes no sense if you sent them through the internet as you have described.  Could you please diagram how exactly you sent, received and captured said packets?

Comment: @MikePennington The setup was just your usual 2 hosts, each behind a typical home modem/router and I would run my test program on host2 which would send the test packets to host1 which is where I'd capture from. The src/dst addresses are the same because they're of my router and machine (host1), respectively, and TTL I would expect to be the same given that it's the same route each time and the capture is over a very short time period leaving little chance of a route change.

Comment: Then it's incumbent on you to prove that you really are sending those packets over the internet.  Evidence says you are not sending them.  Sadly, this question is off-topic here, specifically home networking gear is off-topic.  Please consider asking on [su]

Comment: If you think it is one of the routers, take them out of the picture. What happens when you connect two hosts directly? What happens if you try it with routers, but without NAT?

Comment: @MikePennington I already addressed your misunderstanding of the link-layer and TTL in my previous comment.

Comment: @Gerben After discovering both routers supported bridging that's what I did and (as elaborated in my answer below) it turned out the behavior was due to an implementation quirk in one of them.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site for network professionals to ask and provide answers about professional networks. Unfortunately, questions about home networks and consumer devices are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that one of the routers (a Billion 7300GRA) was to blame; its handling of packets with a protocol ID of 0xFD is what was responsible for the observed behavior and after simply using a different ID (0x8F only tested) the problem ceased.

(I should've updated this question earlier. Sorry about that)

Answer (score -2):

Reconfigure your ISP modem to assign publicly routable IP addresses to the test computers/routers so to avoid NAT/PAT alltogether.

Hope that helps.

Why are you doing this?

Comment: Although this is already resolved, to answer: I'm writing a drop-in replacement protocol for TCP for a pre-existing application (a game) to exploit particular characteristics of it's application-layer protocol. Originally it would be atop UDP but figured for some particular setups (e.g, those with a public IP address) I could just as easily layer it atop IP and save some bytes at the same time.